# SQLite invalid URI after updating System.Data.SQLite.dll

Tags: c#, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I first had this SQLite version: 1.0.77.0 (sqlite-netFx40-static-binary-bundle-Win32-2010-1.0.77.0)
and everything was working fine.
After updating my System.Data.SQLite.dll to version 1.0.82.0 (sqlite-netFx40-static-binary-bundle-Win32-2010-1.0.82.0) I now receive this:

Unable to open database. Connection string: 'datetimeformat=ISO8601;synchronous=Off;uri="file://C:/Users/username/Documents/data/test.db";version=3;journal mode=Truncate;default isolationlevel=ReadCommitted;pooling=True'; Error: 'System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid connection string: invalid URI

I've also tried file:/// instead of file:// without any luck.

Could anybody tell me what is wrong with my URI, why it doesn't work anymore in v1.0.82.0 but worked in v1.0.77.0?

http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki
(1.0.82.0 == 3.7.14)

Comment: What happens if you use a `DataSource` string instead of a `Uri`?

Comment: Haven't tried that... any documentation on this? what are the differences/limitations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to get correct connection string is to always use the `SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder` class to generate them.

```
SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder conn_builder = new SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder 
{ 
   DateTimeFormat = SQLiteDateFormats.ISO8601,
   SyncMode = SynchronizationModes.Off,
   Version = 3,
   JournalMode = SQLiteJournalModeEnum.Truncate,
   DefaultIsolationLevel = System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted,
   Pooling = true,
   Uri = new Uri(@"c:\tmp\db.sqlite").AbsoluteUri
 };
 string conn_str = conn_builder.ConnectionString;
```

if `Uri` is not working, try setting `DataSource` instead (if you are using a local file).

A quick check shows that `DataSource` is evaluated before `Uri` in [SQLiteConnection.cs](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/artifact/35f31d13fceb4e2e7172a9fae32bca99cfd044bb) and takes precedence over it, so if there is a bug in the `Uri` handling, using DataSource may help bypassing it.

Comment: we use the SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder, which looks exactly like this (except the uri is passed as a variable).

Comment: Have you tried using `DataSource` just to make sure everything else is ok?

Comment: Now I receive this when using 
builder.DataSource = myURI.AbsoluteUri; 

Unable to open database. Connection string: 'datetimeformat=ISO8601;synchronous=Off;uri=file:///C:/Users/username/Documents/test.db;version=3;journal mode=Truncate;default isolationlevel=ReadCommitted;pooling=True'; Error: 'System.NotSupportedException: The given path's format is not supported.
   at System.Security.Util.StringExpressionSet.CanonicalizePath(String path, Boolean needFullPath)

Comment: when I use builder.DataSource = this.Uri.AbsolutePath; It sometimes works. but i'm not sure if this is a good way :s

Comment: What I meant was to use the path directly into `DataSource`, without going through the `Uri`  object at all. So you say it sometimes work? You mean not always? Is said file reliably accessible through other method? such as using one of the many SQLite managers?

Comment: "sometimes work" when I hard code the path @"c:\..." it works. Using a path variable with same content it doesn't.

Comment: I found the solution I think. 
builder.DataSource = Uri.AbsolutePath.Replace(@"\\", @"\").Replace("%20", " ");
I just took the path from the uri, but if I get it via another way I still need to replace the double backslashes to a single backslash and replace the %20 with an empty space. 
Very strange that this is the only thing that works.
Thank you for your DataSource suggestion. What does this actually change instead of using Uri?

Comment: SQLite documentation simply describes `DataSource` as an alternative to `Uri`. I think it assumes you are providing a local path, but the only way to know for sure would be to check the source code for `System.Data.SQLite`. Glad you found a work around ... albeit an ugly one.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/news.wiki) starting from the version 1.0.82.0 it was changed:

> Add support for URI file names via the new FullUri connection string
>   property.

Example:

```
var connection = new SQLiteConnection("FullUri=file:mydb.sqlite?cache=shared");
```

Answer (score 1):

following works for me, for following example you can't not use Data Source

```
FullUri=file::memory:?cache=shared
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to strip down your connection string to the basics and then add the options.

Take a look at this site for example SQLite connection string options.

http://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlite

The 3 /// is only valid when you are trying to escape out the spaces in the uri, I would also say that you should try moving the db out of the users folder to the root on c:\ in case the access permissions are not valid for it to access the DB and it also means a simpler connection string for you to try.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

See [these URI filename examples](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html#urifilenameexamples), but your URI (with three slashes) looks correct.

Comment: It didn't work with three slashes (because that was some kind of bug in v1.0.77.0 that it worked with two slashes instead of three slashes). but changing this this doesn't work in v1.0.82.0